# Вывод яндекс карты в модальном окне

Tags: php, javascript, cms, modx

Используя плагин yandexmaps, пытаюсь вывести яндекс карту в модальном окне.

Вот так:

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Показать всплывающее окно</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Заголовок окна</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                [[!yandexMaps?
                    &tvCoords=`coords`
                    &fieldForBalloonContent=`description`
                    &fieldForHint=`pagetitle`
                    &objectsTypesJSON=`[
                        {
                            "InvestProjects": {
                                "parent":"5",
                                "preset":"islands#violetStretchyIcon",
                                "presetText":"Реализованный",
                                "title":"Инвестиционные проекты"
                            },
                            "InvestPlaygrounds": {
                                "parent":"6",
                                "icon":"/images/playgrounds_map_icon.png",
                                "title":"Инвестиционные площадки"
                            }
                        }
                    ]`
                ]]  
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Но она даже не помещается в модальное окно, сразу выводится, а, когда открываю модальное, оно пустое.

Comment: а где код с картой

Comment: ой не вставилась, исправил

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
<script>
    ymaps.ready(function () {

    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
            zoom: 9
        },
        {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),


    myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap.getCenter(), {

            hintContent: 'Собственный значок метки',
            balloonContent: 'Это красивая метка'
        });

    myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);

    var myGeocoder = ymaps.geocode("[[#24.adressminsk]]");

myGeocoder.then(
    function (res) {
     myPlacemark.geometry.setCoordinates(res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates());
    myMap.setCenter([res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates()[0], res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates()[1]], 9, {
    checkZoomRange: true
});

    },
    function (err) {
        alert('Ошибка');
    }
);

});
</script>
```

Comment: я же вывожу снипетом

Comment: В первые минуты снипета небыло )) 
Недумаю что с снипетом можно активировать карту в модальном окне(сам снипет никогда не использовал), т.к надо инициализировать карту после открытия модального окна, правильно бы использовать API Yandex map.
Насколько я помню в Яндекс снипетах карта не выводится, а вставляется ссылка на карту

Comment: а как мне потом вывести все городаданнй категории, т.е. есть категория каталог и в ней 20 ресурсов и у каждого город, и на этой карте мне нужно будет отобразить 20 адресов

Comment: я бы использовал Yandex Map API, и просто вставил все кординаты (маркеры) на одной карте. Почитайте документацию, может поможет
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/quick-start/tasks/quick-start-docpage/

Comment: а как по горорду получить координаты? просто при добавлении ресурса заполняется город, а координаты нет

Comment: @Aslero для этого необходимо геокодирование, можете сделать поиск по городу и адресу и API вам выдаст кординаты, по которым вы уже сможете поставить маркер ) более детально можете почитать тут
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.0/dg/concepts/geocoding-docpage/

Comment: var myGeocoder = ymaps.geocode("[[#24.adressminsk]]");
myGeocoder.then(
    function (res) {
        alert('Координаты объекта :' + res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates());
     myMap.geoObjects.add(res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates().getCenter());
        
    },
    function (err) {
        alert('Ошибка');
    }
);

как привязать к карте?

Comment: var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
            zoom: 9
        },
        {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),
        myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap.getCenter(), {
            hintContent: 'Собственный значок метки',
            balloonContent: 'Это красивая метка'
        });
    myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);

Comment: @Aslero в ответе я поменял данный код, маркер нольмально вставляется и центрируется, ты неправильно задавал центр!

Comment: а если мне нужно несколько меток, то есть в modx revo я вывожу ресурсы и на карту вставляю по городу, т.е. на карте в результате может быть 100 меток адресов?

Comment: @Aslero вам надо получить все адреса из базы, сделать цикл(for) пройтись по адресам и каждый раз в цикле вставлять маркер по адресу....

Comment: а он ведь их вставляет в центр, как сделать чтобы выводил в разных местах а не в центре

Comment: Если маркеры находятся на больших растояниях(разные города) надо просто уменьшить свойство zoom. тогда все маркеры будут видны.

Comment: в выше указанном ответе у меня вывод города, если я вставляю еще один, то он выводит последний